# JS Only excute calculation if possible

Tags: javascript

I want a calculation in a string only to be executed if the calculation doesn´t return an error

For example, `eval('abc')` returns a `SyntaxError`,
but `eval('1+2')` returns `3`.

I couldn´t find any solution, `instanceof` doesn´t work either:

```
if (eval('abc') instanceof Error) {
  console.log('error');
} else {
  console.log(eval('abc'));
}
// Uncaught ReferenceError: abc is not defined at eval
```

Comment: Try-catch the SyntaxException?

Comment: provide code of `eval()`, your code depends on this function.

Comment: @MuhammadZakaria eval is part of JavaScript: [eval() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: @Muhammed Zakaria ```eval()``` is a built in function in Javascript [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***try catch***

```js
try {
  if (eval('abc') instanceof Error) {
    console.log('error');
  } else {
    console.log(eval('abc'));
  }
}catch(e){
  console.log(e, "error");
}
```